# Server accepting file name from client

Tags: java

Server part send to client list of available files in directory, client chooses one of them, then request from client is send to server, and then server send file to client. I have problem with server, I don't know how to accept requested file name from client, maybe some one have an idea?

Server part:

```
import java.io.*;
import java.net.*;
public class Server {
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    ServerSocket ss = null;
    try {
        ss = new ServerSocket(9999);
    } catch(IOException e) {
        e.getStackTrace();
    }
    while(true) {
        try {
            Socket s = ss.accept();
            System.out.println("Connection: " +s);
            PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(s.getOutputStream(), true);
            BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(s.getInputStream()));
            String fileName = getFileName("E://share//");
            //sending available files names to client
            out.println(fileName);
            out.close();
            //System.out.println("File requested from client:");
            //String file = in.readLine();
            //System.out.println(file);
            s.close();
        } catch(IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } 
        //ss.close();
    }
}//methode which get file names from directory
public static String getFileName(String folderName) {
    File folder = new File(folderName);
    File[] listOfFiles = folder.listFiles();
    StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
    for(int i=0; i<listOfFiles.length; i++) {
       //System.out.println(listOfFiles[i].getName());
       sb.append(listOfFiles[i].getName()+"\n");
       }
    return sb.toString();
}
}
```

Client part:

```
import java.io.*;
import java.net.*;
public class Client {
public static void main(String[] args) {
try {
    Socket s = new Socket(InetAddress.getLocalHost(),9999);
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(s.getInputStream()));
    //for gettin file name from available
    PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(s.getOutputStream(), true);
    BufferedReader sin = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
    //output from server, available file list
    String fileNames;
    while((fileNames = br.readLine()) != null) {
        System.out.println(fileNames);
    }
    br.close();
 //imputing file name which have to be send from server to client
    System.out.println("Which file do you want to send:");
    String fileName = sin.readLine();
    out.println(fileName);
    out.close();
    s.close();
} catch(IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}

}
}
```

Comment: The server can read the socket output the same way the client reads it's socket output. Use `in.readLine()`

Comment: I use inreadLine(); but it doesn't work, that's why i commented it

Comment: It skips the part, when client inputs the file name which ir needed, i don't know how to repair that.

Comment: What do you mean by "it doesn't work"?

Comment: It doesn't skip anything. If it's not reading it then you are not sending it.

Comment: It skips the input from client

Comment: I have another project where i tested sending request from client to server it worked correctly, also i have a project where i test sending available file list to client, it's also works, but a i can't combine them two.

Comment: Are you say that if you add that line to the server, the client doesn't ask the user which file to use?

Comment: yes, idea is that the client inputs file name, and then server accpets file name which it have to send to client, but i can't input file name at client part, it just skips it

Comment: The error is of client side where I output names of available files, while cycle, but if I take it out I have only one file in utput, how can i change it?

Comment: What does it do when it skips it? Does it error? set the filename to null or empty string?  Can you print out the filename to see what is sent?

Comment: When i start the client after the server, it's simply skips client, he output at server side..
"File requested from client:" and there's nothing is writen, because it skips client side.

Comment: if nothing were written it would wait forever. if you don't see anything it is more likely that an empty string early sent. I suggest you print exactly what is sent and received by printing the filename at both ends in quotes.

Comment: i don't know how to do that

Comment: Add `System.out.println("The filename is >" + filename + "<");` to the client and server.  BTW I assume you have stepped through the code in your debugger to understand what it is doing. ;)

Comment: I don't undesrtand why do i have to list file in server part, i just simply need to list avalable files at CLIENT par, not server, i try to list then at

    while((fileNames = br.readLine()) != null) {
             System.out.println(fileNames);
       }

,but he doesn't list then and ask for request


yours line System.out.println("The filename is >" + filename + "<");

simply does nothing

Comment: SERVER sends list of available files, CLIENT receives the list, then CLIENT writes filename, SERVER receives reques and SERVER send FILE to CLIENT, that's all, but you gave me line which does nothing

Comment: there's a bug with CLIENT when he tries to output the list, it's while cycle, if i write only one file, then everything work fine, but a have list them all.